# Get the data after colon and display in different lines

Tags: java, string, split

i have a String like this :

```
"I have 2 friends: (i) ABC (ii) XYZ"
```

Now how to display like this:

```
I have 2 friends:

(i) ABC
(ii) XYZ
```

I am displaying the data dynamically so i have to check if the string contains :(colon).

i tried getting like this `string.contains(":")` but i am not getting how to proceed further?

Comment: Can you post some code and what you have tried to do?

Comment: Will your string always be in this format?

Comment: i am trying to check if the string.contains(":") then i am am not getting how to get the remaining data

Comment: `String.contains()` is a good attempt.  But look at `String.indexOf()` and `String.substring()` methods now.

Comment: yes if i have a String with colon then it will contain atleast one (i)

Comment: Looks like more complicated task is to split `(i) ABC (ii) XYZ` into `(i) ABC` and `(ii) XYZ)`.

Comment: Ok, here's a hint. First split your string on whitespace preceded by `:` - Use `look-behind` here. then split your 2nd element of array on whitepsace followed by `(` - Use `look-ahead` here.

Answer (score 3):

```
String s = "I have 2 friends: (i) ABC (ii) XYZ";
s = s.replace(':',':\n');
s = s.replace('(','\n(');
```

(not a generalized solution, but assuming your "list of friends" formatting is constant and the colon indicates presence of the list... you can wrap in an if(s.contains(':')){ ... } block if needed)

Comment: please wait i am just checking

Comment: hey i check your code it works fine but my text might contain like this (i) ABC (sss) (ii) XYZ in that  case? can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "I have 2 friends: (i) ABC (ii) XYZ";
String [] parts = s.split (":");
System.out.println (parts [0]);
System.out.println ();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile ("\\([^)]+\\)[^(]*").matcher (parts [1]);
while (m.find ()) System.out.println (m.group ());
```

Output is:

```
I have 2 friends

(i) ABC 
(ii) XYZ
```

Comment: it works fine but only one small thing i need from you is, now html.append("<p>"+parts [0]+"</p>"); and in while loop 
html.append("<p>"+m.group ()+"</p>");
i have some space between ABC and XYZ line how to remove that? here html is string buffer

Answer (score 2):

You can use indexOf and substring methods of the String class to gain this.

```
System.out.println(str.substring(0, str.indexOf('(', 0)));
System.out.println();
System.out.println(str.substring(str.indexOf('(', 0), str.indexOf('(', str.indexOf('(', 0) + 1)));
System.out.println(str.substring(str.indexOf('(', str.indexOf('(', 0) + 1)));
```

Comment: hey it works but you have shown here only if its 2 data like (i) and (ii) if i have n items how can i loop?

Answer (score 0):

The following will solve your specific problem:

```
String str = "I have 2 friends: (i) ABC (ii) XYZ";

int indexOfColon = str.indexOf(":");
int lastIndexOfOpenParenthesis = str.lastIndexOf("(");

String upToColon = str.substring(0, indexOfColon);
String firstListItem = str.substring(indexOfColon + 1, lastIndexOfOpenParenthesis);
String secondListItem = str.substring(lastIndexOfOpenParenthesis);

String resultingStr = upToColon + "\n\n" + firstListItem + "\n" + secondListItem;
```

Check out the [java.lang.String documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for all your string manipulation needs! (within Java)

Comment: are you there? can you help me?